# Wake from sleep using USB device attached to docking station?

Tags: usb, sleep, thinkpad, wake-up, docking-station

Is it possible to wake a laptop (Lenovo T410 in this case) via a USB keyboard or mouse connected to the docking station?  I moved my dock off my desk to reclaim space, but the power button is a bit of a pain to reach now.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old thread, but it still appears high on some search results. Lenovo removed the capability to wake from USB from recent(ish) docks: https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht077684

From the linked article:

> ### Problem
>
> The USB mouse or keyboard attached, either wired or wirelessly, will not wake the ThinkPad from the S3 (Standby) state by pressing the mouse buttons or the keyboard buttons if the USB devices are attached to the ThinkPad dock.
>
> ### Limitations
>
> This is not a limitation of the ThinkPad dock or of ThinkPad notebook systems.  This function is by design.
>
> NOTE: This issue also pertains to Wireless USB mice and wired USB mice.
>
> ### Solution
>
> Press the ThinkPad dock Power button to resume the system from the S3 (Standby) state or attach the USB devices directly to USB ports on ThinkPad system.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, well it depends on which keyboard and which mouse it is. Some do not have specified buttons that would be able to do so.

Answer (score 1):

If available, this BIOS setting should be *On*: **Always On USB**.

- Verified on a Lenovo T14s with USB mouse and keyboard attached to a ThinkPad USB-C Dock device.
- The laptop wakes up from sleep when either the USB mouse is moved or a key on the keyboard is pressed.

**Background**

This article, [How to stop Mouse and Keyboard from waking Windows from sleep mode](https://techcult.com/how-to-stop-mouse-and-keyboard-from-waking-windows-from-sleep-mode/), has the opposite goal.

- In Windows, the article recommends turning off this setting for each mouse or keyboard: **Allow this device to wake up the computer.**
- But regardless of the Windows settings on my Lenovo T14s, a USB mouse or keyboard could still wake up the laptop from sleep.
- Whether attached the USB-C Dock or to the laptop directly, the mouse or keyboard woke up the laptop.
- The breakthrough was changing this BIOS setting *Off*: **Always On USB**
- Afterwards, neither the USB mouse nor USB keyboard could wake up the laptop.
- Therefore, to allow a USB mouse or keyboard to wake up the laptop, make sure this BIOS setting is *On*: **Always On USB**